# Error in Avg Function in ms Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

In attendance table there is a field `TimeIn` of the type Date/Time. Some data in that column is

```
14/03/2015 15:06:45
```

While some is in the format

```
15:08:40
```

Want to find average time the Employee has entered Office. Hence I used the below SQL

```
SELECT  AvgTimeIn = CAST(AVG(CAST(TimeIn as FLOAT)) as DATETIME)        
FROM tblAttendanceHrs
GROUP BY tblAttendanceHrs.Staff;
```

Getting Error as

[image]

Comment: Cast does not exist in MS Access SQL. You are using SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fionnuala

I got the average time in by using this Query

```
SELECT Cdate (Avg(AttandanceTbl.TimeIn)) AS AvgOfTimeIn
FROM AttandanceTbl
GROUP BY AttandanceTbl.Staff;
```

Source : http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/953801-how-average-time-ms-access-2003-a